# Modify price components from Commerce Shipping without altering the module itself

Tags: commerce

I use Drupal Commerce with [Commerce Shipping](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) and [Commerce Flat Rate](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate).

I have a client who wants the shipping line item in the *commerce summary cart* to come before the tax line item. My problem lies in that Commerce Shipping doesn't expose the weight of each shipping service when it implements the `hook_commerce_price_component_type_info` as seen below.

I have tried to use the mentioned hook in one of my own modules and with a lower value for the weight. This produces an error in the Commerce Price module where it tries to do the addition `array(20, -50) + 1`. Somehow, the Commerce Price module creates an array of the values instead of overwriting.

The weight I'm trying to overwrite is the one in the foreach loop.

Once I have solved this, I'll need to subtract the tax component on the shipping line item, but that's another problem which I can probably figure out by myself.

*Line 110 to 135 in commerce_shipping.module.*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_price_component_type_info().
 */
function commerce_shipping_commerce_price_component_type_info() {
  $components = array();

  // Define a generic shipping price component type.
  $components['shipping'] = array(
    'title' => t('Shipping'),
    'weight' => 20,
  );

  // Add a price component type for each shipping service that specifies it.
  foreach (commerce_shipping_services() as $name => $shipping_service) {
    if ($shipping_service['price_component'] && empty($components[$shipping_service['price_component']])) {
      $components[$shipping_service['price_component']] = array(
        'title' => $shipping_service['title'],
        'display_title' => $shipping_service['display_title'],
        'shipping_service' => $name,
        'weight' => 20,
      );
    }
  }

  return $components;
}
```

PS. [Tax rate on shipping price](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/tax-rate-on-shipping-price) is not the same as my problem. DS.

Comment: Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate ? You need shipping 2.x

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. That's the module I'm using with Commerce Shipping. As far as I know, there isn't any way of setting the weight of the shipping line item's weight. I should emphasize that I don't need to change the weight of each shipping service (for the shipping pane/page), only in the review pane and the checkout pane.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you want to alter the order in where this components are displayed in the checkout process.

What I've done for *minor* tweaks on this area is using a preprocess of the components theme function, for example:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_commerce_price_formatted_components(&$variables) {
}
```

There you've got $variables and all the components, including the shipping ones so you can tweak some things of the display.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Hook

hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter

For more details on this hook refer : http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!price!commerce_price.api.php/function/hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter/DC